# What is the logic prove $(\mathcal{M},v)\vdash(\psi_1\land\psi_2)$ will lead to $(\mathcal{M},v)\vdash\psi_1$ and $(\mathcal{M},v)\vdash\psi_2$?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Hi I'm learning first order logic, and would like to prove that $(\mathcal{M},v)\vdash(\psi_1\land\psi_2)$ is equivalent to $(\mathcal{M},v)\vdash\psi_1$ and $(\mathcal{M},v)\vdash\psi_2$ using logic axiom of the following:

1. $((\phi_1\to(\phi_2\to\phi_3))\to((\phi_1\to\phi_2)\to(\phi_1\to\phi_3)))$
2. $(\phi_1\to\phi_1)$
3. $(\phi_1\to(\phi_2\to\phi_1))$
4. $(\phi_1\to((\lnot\phi_1)\to\phi_2))$
5. $(((\lnot\phi_1)\to\phi_1)\to\phi_1)$
6. $((\lnot\phi_1)\to(\phi_1\to\phi_2))$
7. $(\phi_1\to((\lnot\phi_2)\to(\lnot(\phi_1\to\phi_2))))$

I've proved that $(\mathcal{M},v)\vdash\psi_1$ and $(\mathcal{M},v)\vdash\psi_2$ will lead to $\left<\mathcal{M},v\right>\vdash(\lnot(\psi_1\to(\lnot\psi_2)))$ , but cannot prove the revearse.

Thus I would like to ask the logic prove of it. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: You need the axiom defining $\land$ in terms of primitive connectives.

Comment: What Mauro says: you need to tell us exactly how the $\land$ is defined for your system, or else we cannot help you

Comment: Basically Ax.7 is needed, because $p \land q$ is $\lnot (p \to \lnot q)$

Comment: @bram28 the definition of  $\left<\mathcal{M},v\right>\vdash(\psi_1\land\psi_2)$ is $\left<\mathcal{M},v\right>\vdash(\lnot(\psi_1\to(\lnot\psi_2)))$

Comment: @Shore OK, very good. Now, 1 and 3 give you the Deduction Theorem ... are you allowed to use the Deduction Theorem?

Comment: @bram28 do you mean $\Gamma\vdash(\phi_1\to\phi_2)$ is equivalate to $\Gamma\cup\{\phi_1\}\vdash\phi_2$ ?? yes!!

Comment: @Shore Yes, that's what I meant. OK, that's very good, because without that these proofs can get very, very hairy. But with it, it's not so hard. I'll post an Answer soon where I'll show that if $\Gamma \vdash \neg (\phi_1 \to \neg \phi_2)$ then $\Gamma \vdash \phi_1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll do one of the ones you are looking for. I'll leave the other one for you .. hopefully what I do here fore the first one will be enough for you to figure out the second one.

OK, so in addition to axioms 1 and 3 (which are sufficient to prove the Deduction Theorem that if $\Gamma \cup \phi \vdash \psi$ then $\Gamma \vdash \phi \to \psi$), you also have axiom 4 (known as Duns Scotus Law) and axiom 5 (known as (Strong) Law of Clavius). Between those 4 axioms, you have a complete system.

Indeed, axiom 2 can be derived from axioms 1 and 3 (nice exercise!). Using the Deduction Theorem, Axioms 4 and 6 can be quickly shown to be interchangeable. Indeed, let's call axiom 4 'Duns Scotus 1' and we'll call axiom 6 'Duns Scotus 2'. Axiom 7 is an unusual axiom: I assume it is thrown in there to help with the $\land$ (did you use it in the proof that you did?), but again it is not needed as it is derivable as well (another good good exercise).

Let's first show a few helpful results that are true of your system in general and that you can fruitfully use to derive other results.

Here is one: $\vdash \neg \neg \phi \to \phi$

Proof:

$1. \ \neg \neg \phi \ (assumption)$

$2. \ \neg \neg \phi \to (\neg \phi \to \phi) \ (by \ axiom \ 6)$

$3. \ \neg \phi \to \phi \ (MP \ 1,2)$

$4. \ (\neg \phi \to \phi) \to \phi \ (by \ axiom \ 5)$

$5. \ \phi \ (MP \ 3,4)$

So: $\neg \neg \phi \vdash \phi$

And thus by the Deduction Theorem: $\vdash \neg \neg \phi \to \phi$

I'll call this one DNE (Double Negation Elimination)

Another one:  $\vdash (\phi \to \neg \phi) \to \neg \phi$ (called Weak Law of Clavius)

Proof (first half):

$1. \ \neg \neg \phi \ (assumption)$

$2. \ \phi \to \neg \phi \ (assumption)$

$3. \ \neg \neg \phi \to \phi \ (DNE)$

$4. \ \phi \ (MP \ 1,3)$

$5. \ \neg \phi \ (MP \ 2,4)$

So this means:  $\neg \neg \phi, \phi \to \neg \phi \vdash \neg \phi$

So by the Deduction Theorem: $\phi \to \neg \phi \vdash \neg \neg \phi \to \neg \phi$

OK, so then we can do (second half):

$1. \ \phi \to \neg \phi \ (assumption)$

$2. \ \neg \neg \phi \to \neg \phi \ (from \ 1 \ and \ \phi \to \neg \phi \vdash \neg \neg \phi \to \neg \phi)$

$3. (\neg \neg \phi \to \neg \phi) \to \neg \phi \ (Law \ of \ Clavius)$

$4. \neg \phi \ (MP \ 2,3)$

OK, so now we know $\phi \to \neg \phi \vdash \neg \phi$, and thus by the Deduction Theorem: $\vdash (\phi \to \neg \phi) \to \neg \phi$ (Weak Law of Clavius)

Now, allow me to redo that very proof, but using a Natural Deduction (Fitch) style notation. That is, given the Deduction Theorem, we can effectively do a conditional proof: make an assumption, show what follows from it, and conclude with the proper conditional between the assumption and the derived statement. In Fitch we typically cal this $\to \ Introduction$, but in this context let's justify this kind of move by referring to the Deduction Theorem or DT for short.

I am also going to refer to the Strong Law of Clavius (your axiom 5) as $SLC$, and I'll use $DS1$ fpor Duns Scotus 1 and $DS2$ for Duns Scotus 2. OK, so here is that very proof of $\vdash (\phi \to \neg \phi) \to \neg \phi$ again:

$\def\fitch#1#2{\begin{array}{|l}#1 \\ \hline #2\end{array}}$

$\fitch{
1.}{
\fitch{
2. \phi \to \neg \phi}{
\fitch{
3. \neg \neg \phi}{
4. \neg \neg \phi \to \phi \qquad (DNE)\\
5. \phi \qquad MP \ 3,4\\
6. \neg \phi \qquad MP \ 2,5
} \\
7. \neg \neg \phi \to \neg \phi \qquad DT \ 3-6\\
8. (\neg \neg \phi \to \neg \phi) \to \neg \phi \qquad (SLC)\\
9. \neg \phi \qquad MP \ 7,8\\}\\
10. (\phi \to \neg \phi) \to \neg \phi \qquad DT \ 2-9\\
}$

See how nice that is? you can just do everything in 1 proof, rather than splitting up the whole thing into several proofs with a bunch of applications of the Decution Theorem in between. If you've done Fitch proofs, this is a totally intuitive way of doing proofs, even if in the end it is really about an axiom system, rather than a Natural Deduction system.

OK, so now let's show that if $\Gamma \vdash \neg (\phi_1 \to \neg \phi_2)$ then $\Gamma \vdash \phi_1$ (well, what I am really going to show is that $\neg (\phi_1 \to \neg \phi_2) \vdash \phi_1)$, from which your desired result immediately follows).

Here it is:

$\fitch{
1. \neg (\phi_1 \to \neg \phi_2)}{
2.\neg (\phi_1 \to \neg \phi_2) \to ((\phi_1 \to \neg \phi_2) \to \phi_1) \qquad DS2\\
3. (\phi_1 \to \neg \phi_2) \to \phi_1 \qquad MP \ 1,2\\
\fitch{
4. \neg \phi_1}{
5. \neg \phi_1 \to (\phi_1 \to \neg \phi_2) \qquad DS2 \\
6. \phi_1 \to \neg \phi_2 \qquad MP \ 4,5\\
7. \phi_1 \qquad MP \ 3,6\\
} \\
8. \neg \phi_1 \to \phi_1 \qquad DT \ 4-7\\
9. (\neg \phi_1 \to \phi_1) \to \phi_1 \qquad SLC\\
10. \phi_1 \qquad MP \ 8,9\\
}$

P.s. LOL! I thought I needed the Weak Law of Clavius for the last proof, but I didn't. So, I didn't need that one .. nor did I need DNE: all you needed were axioms 5 and 6 and the Deduction Theorem (from axioms 1 and 2).  Anyway, I'll leave the proofs of DNE and Weak Law of CLavius in here for prosperity.